# Unexpected data in protobuf stream

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

I'm currently working on a small project to attempt to decode a protocol buffer stream in JavaScript, and I'm seeing some very odd data that doesn't match the encoding spec (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding).

I do not have access to the .proto files so I can't double check and see what the fields look like, so I'm pretty much just coding to the encoding spec and hoping it works.

Here is an example of an object that appears to be encoded properly (note the binary data has been converted into decimal and all characters in the two strings have been changed to the 'x' characters for security reasons):

```
8 6 18 15 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 26 3 88 88 88
```

According to spec, this should be parsed in the following way:

```
8 - field number 1, wire type 0
6 - first and last byte of varint, value 6
18 - field number 2, wire type 2
15 - string length of 15 characters
88 - x (times 15)
26 - field number 3, wire type 2
3 - string length of 3 characters
88 - x (times 3)
```

So this would end up parsing to the following data:

```
field 1: 6
field 2: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
field 3: xxx
```

Now here is an object that doesn't parse correctly:

```
8 56 58 18 12 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 88 26 7 88 88 88 88 88 88 88
```

Running this through my parser, I get the following:

```
8 - field number 1, wire type 0
56 - first and last byte of varint, value 56
58 - field number 7, wire type 2
18 - string length of 18 characters
at this point the next 18 characters are parsed as "byte" data, which is clearly not correct
```

My question/confusion is around the first 4 bytes of the second message:

```
8 56 58 18
```

It really seems like there is a 2 byte varint there, with the 56 and 58, but the high bit of 56 obviously isn't set, so when trying to parse a varint it ends there.

Does anyone know why this extra byte seems to be creeping in, and how I'm supposed to deal with it? The protobuf encoding spec doesn't seem to indicate anything that looks similar.

**Update:**

I have not managed to figure this out yet, but I have found out I can run the same binary data through the protoc command, which spits out a valid object, so it's clearly valid. I might investigate their code when I have a chance to see how they do it